# From Xterm to a full Ubuntu Unity session

Tags: ubuntu, xorg

I am setting up a large-ish network where users have pre-cooked Xvnc sessions created for them in advance. They can also reset those session via a web interface. We plan on releasing this as free software.

One of the requirements is starting a *proper* Ubuntu/Unity session starting from a "naked" X server (basically, just "X" running).

My understanding is that this includes:

- Launching dbus
- Running Unity

I am after the *full* desktop environment, with top menu changing depending on the application shown, DBUS fully working, shortcuts working (CTRL-ALT-T), etc.

While for other environments it's easy to figure out what to run (the panel, the file manager, you're good to go), with Ubuntu I just cannot find the right sequence... help?

Things I tried already:

- running just `unity` from Xterm. Result: tons of dbus errors, etc.
- running `dbus-launch unity` -- same results
- I *tried* running the dbus daemon, but effectively failed
- I tried running `gnome-session --session=ubuntu` -- I only get the background

Answer (score 0):

Don't know offhand, but [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/320084) suggests that the file `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/unity.session` (or perhaps `ubuntu.session`) should indicate what the required components are.

Comment: Nope it doesn't work

Comment: Would you please edit your question to show what exactly you tried?  That will help others who may know more than I do.

Comment: Done! I guess it's better now...